# Mercurial commit only modified and deleted files

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

What is the mercurial equivalent of `git commit -a` to avoid specifying all the files in each commits?

Thanks

Comment: `git commit -a` is not a Mercurial command. If you mean "what is the Mercurial equivalent of `git commit -a`", it's just `hg commit`, since Mercurial has no index in the first place.

Comment: `hg commit -m "msg"` will automatically commit my modified / deleted files if they were added in a previous commit ?

Comment: Mostly. Mercurial does need to be informed about new or deleted files.  However, `git commit -a` also does not know what to do about new or deleted files. `hg commit` has the `-A` or `--addremove` option to make it scan for new or removed files, though I usually prefer to add and/or remove specific files individually.

Comment: One slight correction to my last comment: `git commit -a` does automatically adjust for removed files.  It does not handle added files, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg commit` with no options will automatically commit all modified files under version control.  Untracked files will not be automatically added.  This is the same behaviour as `git commit -a`.

Answer (score 1):

The [hgbook.red](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html) does mention

> The `hg commit` command also provides a `-A` option that performs this same [`hg add-and-remove`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/addremove), immediately followed by a commit.

```
$ echo c > c
$ hg commit -A -m 'Commit with addremove'
adding c
```

But  `hg commit -A` do *not* auto-detect copied/renamed files like `hg addremove -s` can do (`-s` guesses renamed files by similarity)